# Does Lvalue-to-Rvalue conversion occur in function invocation?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int func(){
   int a = 0;
   return a;
}
int main(){
   int result = func();
}
```

According to the cpp standard, some rules about the return statement are:

> 1. A function returns to its caller by the return statement.
> 2. [...] the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by **copy-initialization** from the **operand**

So, the invocation for `int result = func();`, as if it could be translate to:

```cpp
//a fiction code
func(){
   int a = 0;
   int result = a; #1
}
```

Because `a` is a glvalue, it should be converted to prvalue for prvalue evaluation (initialize an object). So my question is, while invocating `int result = func();` in the body of `func`, does the glvalue `a` which as the operand of `return`, need to be converted to a prvalue?

Comment: What do you mean by asking if a conversion happens in a lexical scope (function body)?

Comment: @xskxzr  According to the `return statement` rules,copy-initialize an object from the operand of `return` and according to the `copy-initialize` rules,hence gvalue need to be converted to prvalue  for initialization purpose.  As the answers @M.M has given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `a` undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion as part of initializing the result object  . (Informally this means the value stored in the memory location named `a` is retrieved).

See [dcl.init]/17.8:

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. Standard conversions (Clause 7) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered.

The Clause 7 includes the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: A wonderful answers.I have some other confusions about [stmt.return] and I have post a new question,I hope you can help me understand them.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004727/what-are-rules-about-when-the-return-type-is-reference#61004727

Comment: Why is a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion necessary?

Comment: @xskxzr Because `a` is glvalue ,For initialization purpose,the glvalue need to be converted to prvalue ,hence `lvalue-to-rvalue conversion` is necessary.

Comment: @jackX "For initialization purpose,the glvalue need to be converted to prvalue", why?

Comment: @xskxzr because here https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#1.2.  glvalue expression evaluation is determin the identity of an object

Comment: @jackX The evaluation of a prvalue is used to initialize something does not mean everything used to initialize something needs to be a prvalue.

Comment: @xskxzr initializing an object of built-in type from a glvalue means the glvalue is converted to prvalue to obtain the value to store in the object being initialized

Comment: @xskxzr The concret answers are in the standard,I cite the link here:https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.8 (Note: build-in type) thereof,`Standard conversions` is denoted by lvalue-to-rvalue conversion(in most case) because obtained a value from glvalue ,which need to use the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the result of the conversion is the value saved in an object. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.lval#3.4