# what are rules about when the return type is reference

Tags: c++, return, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int func0(){
  int a = 0;
  return a;
}
int&& func1(){
   int a = 0;
   return a;
}
int main(){
  int&& result0 = func0();
  int&& result1 = func1();
}
```

`return statement` rules are:

> 1. A function returns to its caller by the return statement.
> 2. [...] the return statement initializes the **glvalue result or prvalue result object** of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand.

The rule about how to initialize the object of the function call is only #2.

We know the expression `func0()` is a prvalue. The reference `result0` need to bind an object, so `temporary materialization conversion` shall covert the prvalue to an xvalue, So the temporary object as the prvalue result object is initialized from the operand of `return`, then the reference `reusult0` bind to the temporary object.

But we know the `result1` is a reference and the return type of `func1` is also reference. For this case, **[stmt.return]** does not clearly cover this case, because `result1` is a reference rather than `object`(neither glvalue reuslt object nor prvalue result object), so what the rules about this case? If I miss something, please correct me.

Comment: Why ask this seperately? You could have added this doubt to the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004055/does-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-occur-in-function-invocation) considering your questions to revolve around return statement rules.

Comment: @Anirban166 disagree -- this site uses a "1 question per question" format . This question about returning by reference is substantially different to the other question

Comment: @Anirban166 I think they are different questions.So I open a new post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis of `result0` is correct.

But there's no temporary materialization in the `result1` case.  The "glvalue result" is a reference initialized by copy-initialization from the operand `a`,  and copy-initialization of a reference to the same type means that the reference binds directly (dcl.init.ref/5, via dcl.init/17.2).   Then `result1` binds to the glvalue result.

This creates a dangling reference; a `return` statement is explicitly excluded from the lifetime extension rules (class.temporary/6.2).

In the case `int result2 = func1();` then the glvalue result (a reference) undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion with result object `result2` , this causes undefined behaviour since the glvalue result was dangling.

Comment: so the key point is that glvalue reuslt does not mean `glvalue reuslt object`? I misunderstand the standard said,I took `glvalue reuslt` as `glvalue reuslt object`...

Comment: @jackX the glvalue result may or may not be an object . In this case it is a reference, in the case `int result2 = func1();` it would be an object.

Comment: sorry, For `int result2 = func1();` I think `result2` is also prvalue reuslt object,because for the purpose of initialization,lvalue-to-rvalue conversion shall used to convert glvalue `func1()` to prvalue

Comment: @jackX `result2` is an lvalue since it has a name . `result2` is copy-initialized by `a` which involves lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `a` (i.e. retrieving the stored value of `a`)

Comment: For a example,`int&& a = 0; int b = a;` Do you think `b` is the prvalue reuslt object? I think it is ,because `a` is a glvalue,so it need to be converted to prvalue for initialization purpose.and `The result object of a prvalue is the object initialized by the prvalue`so I think b is .if I misunderstand,please correct me.

Comment: @jackX ok, `b` would be the result object of the result of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `a`

Comment: ok,So I think  in your example ,`int result2 = func1();`,the expression `func1()` is glvalue because the return type is `int&&`,so the expression`func1()` shall be converted to prvalue for initialization.hence I think `reulst2` is prvalue reuslt object  lik the exmple I aforementioned.Do you agree?

Comment: @jackX Yes I agree   (also bear in mind that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion causes  undefined behaviour since the reference dangles).

Comment: yup,I know the local storage object would be cause reference dangles when it initialize an reference since its lifetime will be done at the end of block scope.I ignore the lifetime only for this question itself.But I also just a kind of don't understand `glvalue result` because the standard does not mention it specially,Does it mean `identity of an object`?

Comment: @jackX actually I now think "glvalue result" only means the case of the function returning a reference , and "prvalue result object" means the result object of a prvalue function call (i.e. call of a function that returns by value), even if that result object is named. So maybe my answer needs a bit of editing

Answer (score 2):

> We know the expression `func0` is a prvalue

Incorrect. `func0` (the function name expression) is an lvalue. You are thinking of `func0()` (the function call expression) which is indeed a prvalue. The rest of the paragraph is correct.

I don't really follow your second paragraph so let me phrase it:

`func1()` is an xlvalue and the reference `result` will bind to that xvalue.

Very important: because you are returning a reference to an automatic storage variable you are left with a dangling reference.

Comment: @bolov yup,thanks ,I miswrite it,`func0()` is a prvalue

Comment: about the second paragraph,I think I have misunderstood the `glvalue result`,I took `glvalue result` as `glvalue result object` as far as now.

Answer (score 1):

> For this case, **[stmt.return]** does not clearly cover this case, because
>   result1 is a reference rather than object(neither glvalue reuslt
>   object nor prvalue result object), ...

No, it covers. Note the rule says "glvalue result or prvalue result object", which is not "glvalue result **object** or prvalue result object". See [[basic.lvalue]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#5):

> The *result* of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression. The
>   *result* of a prvalue is the value that the expression stores into its
>   context; a prvalue that has type cv void has no result. A prvalue
>   whose result is the value V is sometimes said to have or name the
>   value V. The *result object* of a prvalue is the object initialized by
>   the prvalue; ...

So the reference entity of the result of `func1()` is initialized with `a`.

Comment: yes,I have misunderstood the `glvalue reuslt`,I took `glvalue reuslt` as `glvalue reuslt object` as far as now,So it is key point

Comment: so `glvalue reuslt` denote the `identity of an object`?

Comment: @jackX "The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression", an entity is not necessarily an object.

Comment: Could you give a link about this in standard?and Is the reference  a glvalue result?

Comment: @xskzr It only talk about how the entity is,It's not say the glvalue result is a entity,where's the sentence "The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression" from?