# Constant function when its parameter is a reference to literal type

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
constexpr int func(int const& rf){
   return rf;
}
int main(){
  constexpr int value = func(0);
}
```

Consider the above code ,it will be compiled and it's well-formed, However I'm confused about this. According to [[[stmt.return#2]]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#2)

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by **copy-initialization** from the operand.

So, I think the return statement would be equivalent to the following:

```cpp
constexpr void func(int const& rf){
   constexpr int value = rf;  //#1
}
int main(){
   func(0);
}
```

However, this time, the code is ill-formed. Because it's subject to these rules:

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a **preceding initialization** and either
>
> > - it is initialized with a constant expression or
> > - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

`rf` has no preceding initialization and its lifetime began before enter the function body, hence, when evaluate the `rf` at `#1`, its lifetime does not begin within the evaluation of this expression. So, the expression is not a constant expression, However, as the equivalent form, I wonder why the first code is well-formed when the object `value` copy-initialized from the operand `rf`?

#### UPDATE

I think these questions are simply equivalent to this form:

```cpp
constexpr int func(){
    int result = 0;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int x = func();
}
```

When a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to the operand `result` of return statement, it would violate the following rule:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
> > - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete **non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression**

`result` is initialized with a constant expression but not a const object, So it violate this rule and would be not a constant expression. why actually it's well-formed? why a constexpr function can return a non-constant variable? As far as now, I haven't found any additional rule to permit this.

Comment: The fact that the return statement initializes `value` (at that call site) doesn’t import the requirements of its `constexpr` into the return statement.

Comment: @DavisHerring  StoryTellerUnslander has given the correct [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522951/11796722)

Comment: Of course that answer is correct, but the main point is much simpler: the question is based on a faulty assumption and doesn’t really need answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I think the return statement would be equivalent to the following

If by equivalent you mean that it would be copy-initialization had it been valid, then yes. But it's not valid, so to call it equivalent is not correct.

> However, as the equivalent form, I wonder why the first code is well-formed when the object value copy-initialized from the operand rf?

Because copy-initialization is not of any importance here. The reason that

```
constexpr int value = func(0);
```

is valid, while

```
constexpr int value = rf;
```

is not, is solely due to the properties of the expression being used in the initialization. The copy-initialization plays no part in disqualifying the second or allowing the first.

For the first example, `func(0)` is the expression that must satisfy the constant expression requirements. It is an expression that produces a prvalue. That prvalue is ultimately copy-initialized from some reference. Yet the reference refers to some object that exists only during constant-evaluation. I.e. the "temporary" that is created to hold `0` before calling the function. That's why the prvalue result can be constant-evaluated, and then used to initialize a `constexpr` variable.

In the second example, `rf` on the other hand is not usable in a constant expression. For the very paragraph you cited. `constexpr` functions are still regular functions, invocable "at runtime" too. Also, the compiler doesn't *have* to constant fold them. And so they must be valid functions irrespective of when they are evaluated. As such, since `rf` is not usable in a constant expression *irregardless* of how the function is called, it cannot be used to initialize something that must be unconditionally initialized by a constant expression inside the function itself.

To put it a bit in the frame of standardese, the full-expression of initialization may access objects created within it. In the context of

```
constexpr int value = func(0);
```

`rf` is bound to an object that came into existence as part of the full-expression. So we may access it. However, in the context of

```
constexpr int value = rf;
```

`rf` is not bound to an object whole lifetime started in *that* full-expression.

Each `constexpr` variable declaration is its own self-contained "context" for checking the validity of the constant expression. They are disjoint from each other in that regard.

---

> `result` is initialized with a constant expression but not a const object, So it violate this rule

It violates *that* bullet, but there are several bullets in that clause that are alternatives for valid lvalue-to-rvalue conversions. It is very much inline with

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
> - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

`result` is of a literal type and came into life (as well as going out of it) during the evaluation of `func()`. It is therefore well-formed.

Comment: I don't think so, Let us analyze the grammar step by step, firstly, in my first code, the `func(0)` is a postfix-expression and it's also a function call.So the rule applied to this expression, that is, `The result of a function call is the result of the operand of the evaluated return statement in the called function (if any)`, `A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.`

Comment: here due to the return type is not reference because it's `int`, hence the result is a prvalue, so, the `value` is the so-called prvalue result object. And reback to analyze the `the operand of the evaluated return statement`, In order to initialize the result object, the operand of the `return statement`, namly, `rf ` required to transformed to a prvalue. So, here `the result of the operand of the evaluated return statement in the called function` is the result from applying lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion on `rf`(because it's the operand of `return statement`).

Comment: >an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>> a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const object with a **preceding initialization**, initialized with a constant expression   

here, applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `rf` satisfies  the requirements after `unless`, howerver `rf` is an id-expression of reference type, and it has not a preceding initialization, so it's violate the [expr.const#2.11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11), it's not a constant expression

Comment: @jack - *"so, the value is the so-called prvalue result object"* - No it's not. The prvalue is independet. It exists even when you don't assign the result of the call to anything.

Comment: @StoryTellerUnslander The lifetime of `result` indeed start within the evaluation of postfix-expression `func()`, but before the conversion when lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to `result` at the point of `return statement`, Note In any constexpr variable declaration, the **full-expression of the initialization** shall be a **constant expression**. It means contain any conversion or implicitly function call.

Comment: @StoryTellerUnslander No, because materialization conversion applied to the prvalue, the temporary object is the prvalue resutl object.  `For a discarded prvalue, a temporary object is materialized; `    Look at  [temporary materialization conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.rval#1) and  [result object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#2)

Comment: @jackX - You did not contradict what I said at all. The prvalue is not an object at all.

Comment: @ StoryTellerUnslander `prvalue result object` does not mean `prvalue`,  `The result object of a prvalue is the object initialized by the prvalue; ` , hence `value ` is the result object, because `func ()` is prvalue, it will initialize `value`（`value` denotes id-expression, not english value）

Comment: @StoryTellerUnslander what confuse you is whether there's a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to operand `result`, I do not say `result` is a prvalue, I say the result from applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `result` is a prvalue.

Comment: @ StoryTellerUnslander  [please see here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#9),  and [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.8), and [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.lval#3.4)

Comment: @ StoryTellerUnslander And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61004055/11796722) is the answers about whether a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion apply to operand of a return statement

Comment: @jackX - I am not confused, only vexed. Refrain from taking a patronizing tone with me. None of what you said is yet to invalidate the answer. The full-expression of the initialization is still a constant expression. Even if we substitute `prvalue result object` into the explanation I gave of `func(0)`, it still does not do anything **[expr.const]** disallowes, ergo its a constant expression.

Comment: @ StoryTellerUnslander I'm sorry. I didn't that. I only want to discuss this question with you. The question itself is a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurred at the point of `return statement`, it's evaluation will violate the rules of [expr.const]. I'm confused about this point

Comment: @jackX - That's fine, but *telling* someone *else* what confuses them is borderline rude. I stopped doing it myself many moons ago when someone pointed it out to me.

Comment: @jackX - As for the question, you assert it violates [expr.const], but it really doesn't. You have yet to point at the rule being violated.

Comment: @ StoryTellerUnslander I apologize for that. My native language is not english. Sometimes, I don't know the `wording` whether could post my meaning correctly and indeed doesn't know the language culture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216469/discussion-between-jack-x-and-storyteller-unslander-monica).